# Google Apps Script Count Timestamp

Tags: google-apps-script, count, timestamp

I am trying to add a count/timestamp each time the date is changed in Column D (Date).
I would like the timestamp to be in Column B.
The count of the changes (to column D) would be in in column A.
I can get the timestamp in column B but I'm having trouble with the count in column A.

Here is a link to my spreadsheet if anyone can help:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1YedI83P5u-1oJj15DTz_MNxlwPiJ4wBfWPOG4Pg-QLA/edit#gid=1546276119

Thank you so much!

The timestamp seems to be working but the code I used for the count was incorrect.
I'm trying to make the code work for multiple month tabs.

Answer (score 0):

When column D date is changed record timestamp in columnB and change count in column A

```
function onEdit(e) {
  //e.source.toast("Entry")
  const sh = e.range.getSheet();
  if(sh.getName() == "Sheet0" && e.range.columnStart == 4 && e.range.rowStart > 1) {
    //e.source.toast("Gate1")
    e.range.offset(0,-3).setValue(e.range.offset(0,-3).getValue() + 1);
    e.range.offset(0,-2).setValue(new Date());
  } 
}
```